# PHP + SQL + JS Dynamic Map

Tags: php, javascript, sql, dictionary

I'm working on an image map in php using the html map tag. The script I have now populates a specific amount of map cells.
You can see what I've done for far here: http://terrachaos.com/doa/map/

I'm having trouble devising an approach to retrieving data from the database based on what map cell the user hovers over. Specifically the coordinates. I want PHP to compare the coordinates x & y to a corresponding row in the db.

I am currently using **simple_html_dom.php** to parse the page containing my map and control attributes.
I'm just not sure how I should use that to dynamically populate the information of each area using data from an SQL database.

I already have the database set up as well as the corresponding php variables that will store the information. Just need someone with more experience to help me with the next steps.

**Main Variables:** *The variables correspond to the names of the database columns.*

- $mType
- $mLevel
- $mCoordx
- $mCoordy
- $mOwner
- $mAlliance
- $mFlag
- $mLord
- $mImage

---

### Main Image Map - index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Ocelot World Map: Sector 0-74</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
        $('.map').maphilight();
    });</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 1000px; position:absolute;">
<div class="title"><h1>Ocelot World Map: Sector 0-74</h1></div>
<div id="image-holder">
<img class="map" src="images/grass.png" width="750" height="750" usemap="#map">
<map name="map">
<?php
// Include Connections
include ("includes/connections.php");

// Dispay Errors (Development use only)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

// Area Vars
$over = "document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'block'";
$out = "document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none'";
$href = 22;
$alt = 00;
$title = 'HelloWorld';
$class = 'areaSelect';
$maxcoord = '74';

// Cell Size & Amount Variables
$columns = 75;
$rows = 75;
$width = 10;
$height = 10;

// Loop to generate values for custom attribute.
for( $coordx = 0; $coordx < $maxcoord; $coordx++ );
for( $coordy = 0; $coordy < $maxcoord; $coordy++ );

// Loop to dynamically generate areas.
for( $x = 0; $x < $columns; $x++ )
{
   for( $y = 0; $y < $rows; $y++ )
   {
      $a = ($x * $width);
      $b = ($y * $height);

      $coords = array( $a, $b, ($a + $width), ($b + $height) );
      echo '<area class="'.$class.'" shape="rect" coords="'.implode( ',', $coords ).'" href="'.$href.'" onmouseover="'.$over.'" onmouseout="'.$out.'" data-coordx="'.$coordx.'" data-coordy="'.$coordy.'" alt="'.$alt.'" title="'.$title.'" />'."\n";
   }
}

// Close Connecction
mysql_close($sql);
?>
</map>
</div>

<div id="info" style="display:none">
    <h4>Area Information</h4>
    <?php include ("script.php"); // Include Simple HTML DOM Script
        list ($mType, $mLevel, $mCoordx, $mCoordy, $mOwner, $mAlliance, $mFlag, $mLord, $mImage) = dataFiller();
    ?>
</div>

<a href="./">Back to Sector Select</a>
</div>
<!-- Java Script Center -->
<!--<script>
var winl = (screen.width - 1000) / 2;
document.getElementById('container').style.left = winl +'px';
</script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

### DOM Parser - script.php

**Note:** *Near the end of the file is a foreach... statement. With the amount of data being populated, it's better I load the information only when it's triggered/needed. Could I get some help making it so? Perhaps a function?*

```
 <?php
    include('includes/simple_html_dom.php'); //Load/include the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.terrachaos.com/doa/map/index.php'); // Load your html file

    // create a series of variables to call on later

    $imgtitle = $html->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext; //here we reference the HTML file, and find the div with the class "title" and display it as plaintext

   // ok for some reason and hopefully someone out there can add why
   // I had to reference the fist instance of each element here 
   // referenced as the ',0' in each case. 

   // here you can see we search for the div 'image-holder'
   // and then search in that div for the first image and save it to a variable

    $imageurl =  $html->find('#image-holder',0)->find('img',0); 

   // here we target the image scr, width, height, style, alt, border and usemap and assign them to variables

    $imagesrc = $imageurl->src;
    $imageWidth = $imageurl->width;
    $imageHeight = $imageurl->height;
    $imageStyle = $imageurl->style;
    $imageAlt = $imageurl->alt;
    $imageBrd = $imageurl->border;
    $imageUsemap = $imageurl->usemap;

    $map = $html->find('map',0); // here we look for the map and assign it to a variable

    // here we target the map ID and Name and usemap and assign them to variables

$mapID = $map->id;
$mapName = $map->name;

    // we assigned a class to the map areas to find them easier
    $imgmaparea = $html->find('.areaSelect');

    // ok although the example only has one map area this will find multiple
    // areas and print them on the screen using the 'foreach' function 
    foreach ($imgmaparea as $value){
     $areaShape = $value->shape;
     $areaCoords = $value->coords;
     $areaHref = $value->href;
     $areaTitle = $value->title;
     $areaAlt = $value->alt;
     $areaCoordx = $value->data-coordx;
     $areaCoordy = $value->data-coordy;
      // print them on the screen
         echo 'Shape: '.$areaShape. '<br>';
     echo 'Coords: '.$areaCoords. '<br>';
         echo 'Href: '.$areaHref. '<br>';
         echo 'Title: '.$areaTitle. '<br>';
         echo 'Alt: '.$areaAlt. '<br>';
         echo 'data-coordx '.$areaCoordx. '<br>';
         echo 'data-coordy '.$areaCoordy. '<br>';

   }
         // print them on the screen
         echo 'name: '.$mapName. '<br>';
         echo 'Id: '.$mapID. '<br>';
         echo 'filename: '.$filename. '<br>';
         echo 'Src: '.$imagesrc. '<br>';
         echo 'Width: '.$imageWidth. '<br>';
         echo 'Height: '.$imageHeight. '<br>';
         echo 'Style: '.$imageStyle. '<br>';
         echo 'Alt: '.$imageAlt. '<br>';
         echo 'Usemap: '.$imageUsemap. '<br>';

   ?>
```

Comment: Lot's of progress from when I last edited. Hope someone out there can help me finish it.

Comment: Made even more changes. Added custom HTML attributes to compare to the SQL table when I make the call. If you're interested in seeing the script in full, you can find it here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,346548.new.html#new

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into using an AJAX call. The way this would work, is your user clicks on the map area, which triggers a Javascript function to make an AJAX request. Your server will handle this as you see fit, and return data back to the user's web browser.

I'd recommend using the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) + its [$.ajax();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) object.

Comment: Well I just recently updated the script. I'm now using PHP to parse the DOM and setting variables to store the values of the area attributes. I posted said script above. It work's near great. Just having some trouble re-wording that for each statement. If I can successfully call the script within a DIV, could I then run some PHP script to fill in the attribute vars with information form the DB dynamically? By the way thanks a ton, here's my progress: [link](http://terrachaos.com/doa/map/)

Comment: @Xerosigma: A guess would be maybe to echo out an attribute of `onClick="someFunction();"`, where `someFunction()` would toggle the call? Or, perhaps `someFunction()` could be passed the content you want to popup or edit, to circumvent the AJAX request?

Comment: I suppose that could work. I'll have to try it out. xD Not too great with the dynamic stuff but I think I might be able to nail it. Thanks a lot. Will post progress.